# Finding value with similar headers in multiple columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to do an Offset/Match or Index/Match type formula to find the value that matches a cell. The problem is the way the sheet is laid out.

For an example I am trying to match the **Job No.** to the **Project** Name under the appropriate client.

I would like to keep it in this format because the project list will grow.

This sheet is where my lists are kept.
*This is just being created hence why the Project lists are tiny.
[image: Lists]

This sheet will be an ever expanding list of stuff that needs to be done.
You can see the `OFFSET` formula below that I tried. Is there another way of doing this or can this be done with a simple formula (instead of a long IF statement for each Client)?
[image: To-Do]

`=OFFSET(D2,MATCH(D3,Lists!F3:P10,0),MATCH(J2,Lists!F3:P3,0))`

Thanks for any feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

=VLOOKUP(D3,OFFSET(Lists!$E$4:$E$10,,MATCH(C3,Lists!$F$2:$P$2,0),,2),2,0)

Answer (score 0):

It seems a bit more awkward to do it with INDEX/MATCH because you have to repeat the column lookup, but here it is

```
IFERROR(INDEX(INDEX($F$4:$P$10,,MATCH(C3,$F$2:$O$2,0)+1),MATCH(D3,INDEX($F$4:$P$10,,MATCH(C3,$F$2:$O$2,0)),0)),"")
```

[image]